# Remove Stack Exchange Android app notifications about expired onebox notifications

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

Recently I got a Stack Exchange Android app notification about a comment that got deleted before I could read it.

I tapped the Stack Exchange Android app notification and it wasn't there. Instead, the most recent one was highlighted as if I'd not read it.

I think the notification should be removed from the Stack Exchange Android app if no longer relevant.

Comment: I never used the app but it should also remove notifications immediately when reading them on the desktop version. I usually like having sound/LED notifications even while I'm on my PC since that way I see the colored LED on my phone and know what's new / what site to check. But e.g. with Facebook it's super annoying since I actually need to unlock my phone and clear the notification manually...

Comment: I've had **dozens** of notifications appear at once: several for the same question. The Android app should only push 1 notification/question.

Comment: @Mooseman: I've never had multiple android notification icons appear at the same time within android (for the SE app). For me it's been one notification, that might list several SE notifications within it.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I usually turn on airplane mode overnight, so in the morning I often get many notifactions pushed at once, even those I had read online.